# ReferenceError: sass is not defined (gulp, rubySass)

Tags: gulp, sass, npm, gulp-sass

Пытался запустить с помощью npm sass
Коды выглядят ниже:

```
gulp.task('sass',  function() {
  return rubysass('./app/styles', {
    precision: 6,
    stopOnError: true,
    cacheLocation: './',
    loadPath: ["app/bower_components"]
 })
 .on('error', sass.logError)
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'))
});
```

В результате вызывает ошибку

```
C:\site\gulp-4>gulp sass
[13:53:59] Using gulpfile C:\site\gulp-4\gulpfile.js
[13:53:59] Starting 'sass'...
[13:53:59] 'sass' errored after 11 ms
[13:53:59] ReferenceError: sass is not defined
```

Может быть зависит от rails.

Answer (score 1):

А у вас sass модуль подключен в gulpfile?
Если нет, то вам нужно его подключить, например:

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
```